# NPM doesn't create symlink for transitive binary file on global npm install

Tags: npm, npm-install, binaryfiles, symlink

I have library which exposes binary file pointing to binary file from another installed dependency, `package.json`'s part example:

```
  "bin": {
    "foo": "./node_modules/.bin/foo"
  }
```

When I publish it and then install it globally using `npm install -g`, I expect NPM to create symlink in `$(npm prefix -g)/bin` folder, but it didn't. If I do symlink manually, I can exec `foo` as expected. Is it expected NPM behaviour when dealing with transitive binary files?